Illustrator stroke sets to default when I ungroup
For the past month, I've been having a lot of trouble converting my lines to strokes in Adobe Illustrator. I've attached screenshots to illustrate my issue.
I have a snowflake design made of lines, to which I've applied my desired stroke weight, color, cap, etc. The design consists of multiple line drawings that I grouped together. When I save the ai. file and reopen it the next day (these are not old files), the grouped design looks fine. However, when I ungroup it, the lines revert to the default stroke, and when I try to outline the strokes, they revert to the default stroke settings as well.
I'm finding it difficult to explain, so I've included some screenshots for clarity. I'm using Adobe Illustrator 2024 and have been using Illustrator for seven years as a graphic designer, but I've never encountered this issue before. Is this a new feature or bug in Illustrator? 

The stroke seems to be applied to the group, not the individual paths.
If you merely want the overall shape and aren't vested in keeping strokes as strokes...

Object > Expand Appearance
Object > Expand
Pathfinder > Unite

That will leave you with a single solid shape, no strokes.
If you want to maintain strokes as strokes...

Note the stroke settings for the Group in the Appearance Panel.
Ungroup
Reapply the same stroke settings now that the strokes are ungrouped

